# C++: Disabling RequireCHAP and RequireMsCHAP2 in the Windows RAS API

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, vpn, ras

I am writing a program that will set up a VPN on a user's computer. My sysadmin told me that the security page of the VPN must have [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rkzy.png) security settings checked, and no others.

I have used [this](https://famellee.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/create-vpn-connection-programmatically-on-windows/) code as a basis for my own. My version sets almost everything correctly, except that it cannot uncheck the 2 boxes titled `Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP)` and `Microsoft CHAP Version 2 (MS-CHAP v2)`. Is it possible to programmatically uncheck those 2 checkboxes while leaving the `Data Encryption` dropdown list set as `Require Encryption`? Here is my code:

```
void createVPN()
{
    DWORD size = 0;
    RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, L"", NULL, &size, NULL, NULL);
    LPRASENTRY pras = (LPRASENTRY)malloc(size);
    memset(pras, 0, size);
    pras->dwSize = size;
    pras->dwType = RASET_Vpn;
    pras->dwRedialCount = 1;
    pras->dwRedialPause = 60;
    pras->dwfNetProtocols = RASNP_Ip;
    pras->dwEncryptionType = ET_Require;
    wcscpy_s(pras->szLocalPhoneNumber, L"meraki.companyname.com");
    wcscpy_s(pras->szDeviceType, RASDT_Vpn);
    pras->dwfOptions = RASEO_RemoteDefaultGateway;

    pras->dwVpnStrategy = VS_L2tpOnly;
    pras->dwfOptions2 |= RASEO2_UsePreSharedKey;
    pras->dwfOptions &= ~(RASEO_RequireCHAP | RASEO_RequireMsCHAP | RASEO_RequireMsCHAP2);//This should unset the CHAP flags, but it doesn't.

    RasSetEntryProperties(NULL, L"CompanyName Meraki VPN", pras, pras->dwSize, NULL, 0);

    RASCREDENTIALS ras_cre_psk = { 0 };
    ras_cre_psk.dwSize = sizeof(ras_cre_psk);
    ras_cre_psk.dwMask = RASCM_PreSharedKey;
    wcscpy_s(ras_cre_psk.szPassword, L"redacted");
    RasSetCredentials(NULL, L"CompanyName Meraki VPN", &ras_cre_psk, FALSE);

    free(pras);
}
```

I am thinking that by setting `pras->dwEncryptionType` to `ET_Require`, that prevents `RASEO_RequireCHAP` and the other CHAP flags from being unset, but in the Windows GUI, it is possible to uncheck them and leave `Data Encryption` set to `Require Encryption`. My sysadmin tells me that the connection will not work if either of the CHAP checkboxes are checked, or if `Data Encryption` is not set to `Require Encryption`. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. You have to set the `RASEO_RequirePAP` switch. Here is the final version of the function:

```
void createVPN()
{
    DWORD size = 0;
    RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, L"", NULL, &size, NULL, NULL);
    RASENTRY rasEntry = {};
    rasEntry.dwSize = sizeof(rasEntry);
    rasEntry.dwType = RASET_Vpn;
    rasEntry.dwRedialCount = 1;
    rasEntry.dwRedialPause = 60;
    rasEntry.dwfNetProtocols = RASNP_Ip;
    rasEntry.dwEncryptionType = ET_Require;
    wcscpy_s(rasEntry.szLocalPhoneNumber, L"meraki.enoble.com");
    wcscpy_s(rasEntry.szDeviceType, RASDT_Vpn);
    rasEntry.dwfOptions = RASEO_RemoteDefaultGateway;

    rasEntry.dwVpnStrategy = VS_L2tpOnly;
    rasEntry.dwfOptions2 |= RASEO2_UsePreSharedKey;
    rasEntry.dwfOptions |= RASEO_RequirePAP;

    RasSetEntryProperties(NULL, L"Enoble Meraki VPN", &rasEntry, rasEntry.dwSize, NULL, 0);

    RASCREDENTIALS ras_cre_psk = { 0 };
    ras_cre_psk.dwSize = sizeof(ras_cre_psk);
    ras_cre_psk.dwMask = RASCM_PreSharedKey;
    wcscpy_s(ras_cre_psk.szPassword, L"passport2k");
    RasSetCredentials(NULL, L"Enoble Meraki VPN", &ras_cre_psk, FALSE);
}
```

I hope this helps somebody.